# Python only works for Admin

Tags: python, powershell, cmd, path

I followed this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y2q_b4ugPWk
and got my cmd to recognize python as a path variable.  But this only works if I open cmd and powershell as an Admin.  How do I get it to work for all users?

As Admin:

```
PS C:\windows\system32> python
Python 3.6.4 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Jan 16 2018, 10:22:32) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

As user:

```
PS C:\Users> python
python : The term 'python' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ python
+ ~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (python:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

PS C:\Users>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With elevated privileges (right-click `powershell.exe`, run as admin)

```
$PathToPython = 'C:\whatever\containingfolderforpythonexe'
$CurrentValue = [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('Path', 'Machine')
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('Path', "$CurrentValue;$PathToPython", 'Machine')
```

Comment: great thanks did the trick, how does this work even with the path "C:\Program Files\py3.5"  not being the actual path to my directory holding the python.exe?

Comment: @Mwspencer You need to change that value to wherever you have the python exe.  Windows is pretty smart overall and will search that directory (I just made a good assumption here)

Comment: Interesting it worked right out of the box, must have been a coincidence?  My python.exe is located in AppData/Roaming/Continuum/Anaconda, so seems strange

Comment: @Mwspencer Yep, I just made a good guess here.  I updated my answer with an update-able variable for future cases

Answer (score -1):

I build a batch opener for my powershell script. Once open in elevated privileges any other script called is also elevated.
I do a similar thing with .vbs to open batch in admin.

```
@ECHO off
ECHO Please Wait.
powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -file "File.ps1"
ECHO.
ECHO PRESS ANY KEY ONCE DEBUGGED
Pause >nul
exit
```

Comment: `@Echo off` means you don't have to see the script on the screen. 
`Please wait` and `PRESS ANY KEY ONCE DEBUGGED` still display

Comment: It means you don't see any output to stdout on your screen without using something like `@ECHO Message here`.  So your "Please wait", etc. messages are never seen.  Commands with output in powershell will still be seen.

Comment: Test the code before you state anything. I have been running that code on 100's of machines with variations and as long as you state `ECHO` first, it will display on screen.

Comment: Hm, must have been thinking of a different directive, thanks for the information